# Program fails to compile with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I have a struct which has the purpose of getting next int type in list (just copy and paste):

```
#ifndef PROMOTE_H_INCLUDED
#define PROMOTE_H_INCLUDED
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/next.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/deref.hpp>
template<class Int_T>
struct Is_Char
{
    enum {value = false};
};
template<>
struct Is_Char<char>
{
    enum {value = true};
};
template<>
struct Is_Char<unsigned char>
{
    enum {value = true};
};

template<>
struct Is_Char<signed char>
{
    enum {value = true};
};
template<class Integral>
struct Promote
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<Integral>::value,"Non integral type is not allowed.");
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_signed<Integral>::value,
                                boost::mpl::vector<char,short,int,long,long long>,
    boost::mpl::vector<unsigned char,unsigned short,unsigned int,unsigned long, unsigned long long>>::type types;

    typedef typename boost::mpl::find<types,
    typename std::conditional<Is_Char<Integral>::value,
    typename std::conditional<std::is_signed<Integral>::value,char,unsigned char>::type, Integral>::type>::type this_type;
    typedef typename boost:: mpl::next<this_type>::type next_type;
    typedef typename boost::mpl::deref<next_type>::type type;

};

#endif // PROMOTE_H_INCLUDED
```

When I try to compile it with VS it works but won't compile with gcc 4.6.1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Promote.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << typeid(Promote<char>::type).name();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting error from gcc that something is wrong with boost (It doesn't even say what the error is):

```
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:81|12|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>::result_'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:104|11|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find_if.hpp:39|17|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, boost::mpl::same_as<char> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find.hpp:28|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:39|113|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\and.hpp|17|warning: base class 'struct mpl_::bool_<false>' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\and.hpp:48|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::and_<boost::mpl::not_<boost::is_same<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> > >, boost::mpl::apply1<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:40|58|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >::apply<void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply_wrap.hpp:46|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::apply_wrap2<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply.hpp:67|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::apply2<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:62|63|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_forward_step<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:101|135|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_impl<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, mpl_::na, boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> > >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:81|12|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>::result_'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:104|11|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find_if.hpp:39|17|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, boost::mpl::same_as<char> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find.hpp:28|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:39|113|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\and.hpp|23|warning: base class 'struct boost::mpl::aux::and_impl<false, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true> >' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:40|58|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >::apply<void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply_wrap.hpp:46|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::apply_wrap2<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply.hpp:67|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::apply2<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:62|63|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_forward_step<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:101|135|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_impl<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, mpl_::na, boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> > >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:81|12|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>::result_'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:104|11|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find_if.hpp:39|17|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, boost::mpl::same_as<char> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find.hpp:28|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:39|113|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\and.hpp|48|warning: base class 'struct boost::mpl::aux::and_impl<true, boost::mpl::apply1<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true> >' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply_wrap.hpp:46|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::apply_wrap2<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply.hpp:67|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::apply2<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:62|63|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_forward_step<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:101|135|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_impl<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, mpl_::na, boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> > >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:81|12|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>::result_'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:104|11|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find_if.hpp:39|17|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, boost::mpl::same_as<char> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find.hpp:28|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:39|113|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp|40|warning: base class 'struct boost::mpl::and_<boost::mpl::not_<boost::is_same<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> > >, boost::mpl::apply1<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<true>, mpl_::bool_<tru|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply.hpp:67|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::apply2<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:62|63|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_forward_step<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:101|135|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_impl<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, mpl_::na, boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> > >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:81|12|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>::result_'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:104|11|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find_if.hpp:39|17|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, boost::mpl::same_as<char> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find.hpp:28|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:39|113|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply_wrap.hpp|46|warning: base class 'struct boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >::apply<void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:62|63|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_forward_step<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:101|135|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_impl<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, mpl_::na, boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> > >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:81|12|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>::result_'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:104|11|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find_if.hpp:39|17|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, boost::mpl::same_as<char> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find.hpp:28|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:39|113|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply.hpp|67|warning: base class 'struct boost::mpl::apply_wrap2<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply.hpp:67|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::apply2<boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> >, void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:79|63|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_backward_step<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::na, boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> > >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:123|139|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_impl<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, mpl_::na, boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> > >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:81|12|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>::result_'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:104|11|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find_if.hpp:39|17|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, boost::mpl::same_as<char> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find.hpp:28|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:39|113|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply_wrap.hpp|46|warning: base class 'struct boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> >::apply<void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:79|63|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_backward_step<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::na, boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> > >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\iter_fold_if_impl.hpp:123|139|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_impl<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, mpl_::na, boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> > >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:81|12|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>::result_'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:104|11|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find_if.hpp:39|17|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, boost::mpl::same_as<char> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find.hpp:28|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:39|113|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\gcc\apply.hpp|67|warning: base class 'struct boost::mpl::apply_wrap2<boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> >, void, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l> >' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp:104|11|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::iter_fold_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find_if.hpp:39|17|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, boost::mpl::same_as<char> >'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find.hpp:28|8|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::find<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:39|113|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\iter_fold_if.hpp|81|warning: base class 'struct boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_impl<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 0l>, void, mpl_::arg<1>, boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::iter_fold_if_pred<boost::mpl::protect<boost::mpl::aux::find_if_pred<boost::mpl::same_as<char> >, 0>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 5l> >, 0>, mpl_::na, boost::mpl::always<mpl_::bool_<false> > >' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:39|113|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\find.hpp|28|warning: base class 'struct boost::mpl::find_if<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, boost::mpl::same_as<char> >' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\vector\aux_\iterator.hpp:40|44|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 1l>'|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\deref.hpp:30|37|instantiated from 'boost::mpl::deref<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<char, short int, int, long int, long long int>, 1l> >'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\Promote.h:41|57|instantiated from 'Promote<char>'|
C:\metaprogramming_excersizes\Just_Promote\main.cpp:8|33|instantiated from here|
D:\Libraries\boost_1_47_0\boost_1_47_0\boost\mpl\vector\aux_\at.hpp|40|warning: base class 'struct boost::mpl::aux::wrapped_type<boost::mpl::aux::type_wrapper<short int> >' has a non-virtual destructor [-Weffc++]|
||=== Build finished: 30 errors, 100 warnings (0 minutes, 22 seconds) ===|
```

Comment: Does boost mpl work on other projects?

Comment: There's only warnings here. Where is the error?

Comment: @RedX yes, boost::mpl works on other projects without any problems

Comment: @selalerer that's the whole problem. I do not see what's the error is because is not being listed. Try to compile it and see for yourself

Comment: "||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|": Could you please do this in your IDE until the actual error shows up?

Comment: @thiton ok I've changed number of errors to unlimited. See my edit.

Comment: @thiton but I had to cut something out (I've cut from the top so warnings only) - there was just too many chars and didn't want to accept it. But even by doing so there are still no errors shown. I think the best way to do it is to try compile it and see it for yourself.

Comment: Works quite fine for me with g++ Debian 4.6.0-10 called as "g++ -std=c++0x".

Answer (score 4):

On line 34 `boost::mpl::vector<unsigned char,unsigned short,unsigned int,unsigned long, unsigned long long>>::type types;` you have a right shift where I presume you want to close out the template.

Adding a space between the two right brackets ought to sort it out.

Comment: Well spotted, this also explains why thiton was able to compile under C++0x.

Comment: @Guy Cook This 'right shift' is already supported by this compiler and is being parsed correctly as template's closing brackets. There must be a bug in gcc 4.6.1 then. I've switched compiler to g++ and it also compiles it fine. How can I report a bug to gcc